# JQuery Mobile Dynamic Insertion of UL List Gives Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm working on creating a mobile application with JQuery Mobile and Mustache Templating. But I'm runninng into a problem creating ul list.

A really simple example is this.

```
     var html = '';
        html += '<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="g"><li><a href="acura.html">Acura</a></li><li><a href="audi.html">Audi</a></li><li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li></ul>

$('#listpage #test_view').html(html).trigger('create');
```

The problem I am running into time and time again is an error that looks like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery171025502100912854075' of undefined
```

The fill message is this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery171025502100912854075' of undefined
$.widget._createSubPagesbase:5113
$.widget.refreshbase:4947
$.widget._createbase:4832
$.Widget._createWidgetbase:1065
$.widget._createWidgetbase:1182
$.widget.$.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)base:966
$.widget.bridge.$.fn.(anonymous function)base:1028
e.extend.eachbase:2
e.fn.e.eachbase:2
$.widget.bridge.$.fn.(anonymous function)base:1023
$.widget.enhancebase:1228
$.widget.enhanceWithinbase:1207
$.widget.options.themebase:5198
f.event.dispatchbase:3
f.event.add.h.handle.ibase:3
f.event.triggerbase:3
f.fn.extend.triggerbase:3
e.extend.eachbase:2
e.fn.e.eachbase:2
f.fn.extend.triggerbase:3
setPageContentcomponents:248
displayLoginbase:13133
loginbase:13230
f.Callbacks.nbase:2
f.Callbacks.o.fireWithbase:2
e.extend.readybase:2
c.addEventListener.B
```

This only happens when I try to dynamically create a page. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Two things I see is at the end of the following line add a single quote and a semicolon.

```
html += '<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="g"><li><a href="acura.html">Acura</a></li><li><a href="audi.html">Audi</a></li><li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li></ul> //<- missing single quote and semi colon
```

Corrected:

```
html += '<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="g"><li><a href="acura.html">Acura</a></li><li><a href="audi.html">Audi</a></li><li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li></ul>'; //<- There we go much better
```

Try running your javascript through something like [jshint](http://www.jshint.com/) or [jslint](http://jslint.com) to help you identify errors like this.